# Keeping deploys in Sync

Tags: sockets, websockets

I plan to have a web server, which will serve JavaScript used to make connections, and a socket server which the javascript will talk to.

How can I make sure that when deploying a new update, the javascript and socket server are on the same version and so don't get confused. Do I have to restart both at exactly the same time?

Answer (score 3):

This depends on your architecture.  When you deploy a web client and a web server, you cannot guarantee matching versions even if you deploy both at the same instant.  Even if there is no caching at all, a user may already have a page open.  If it communicates to your server just after you deploy, you'll get that mismatch.

So the key here is *not* to try to deploy both at the same instant but rather to make both resilient so that if and when there *is* a mismatch, things continue to work.

The most important bit of this is making your server backwards compatible.  When change your server, make sure all the calls act the same when called in the manner of the old client.  If you have a nice, regular interface to your server, this is generally not that hard.

If you find you need to make a change to your server that is not backwards compatible, then either change it by adding new calls (so the old ones still work the same) or by adding a client version number (so the system can serve either the old or the new clients.)  But you should avoid this.

The advantage to this goes beyond just worrying about the instant of deployment.  It decouples your front end and back end, making it easier to think about either alone, and to deploy only one or the other, in cases where you need to make a simple change.